# Upload Folder to Onedrive with CMD *Windows*

Tags: windows, cmd, onedrive

i would like to upload a network folder to Onedrive by using CMD.
There is a network folder in my local network which i would like to back up to Onedrive. Since my cloud is 1 TB and my local free Space is 10GB i cant simply clone the folder to my Onedrive folder. 
At the moment i visit onedrive on my browser and upload the Folder once a day. I would like a batch file to do this job.
Do you have any idea how to archive this?
I tried rclone/onedrive-d/SME/Nextcloud on my raspberry pi to safe the folder, but none of them turned out to be reliable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should be specific and your relevant code should be [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I´m looking for the same. Years ago there was a product called Cubby that had a feature that no other cloud bases storage has: you could configure any directory outside of your default one to be part of your storage (Google drive seems to indeed have it) Copying is an easy way to accomplish this, but the file I want to upload is very big and copying it would waste both time and space. It would be great to have something like
copy_onedrive <file path> <one drive path>
Cloud storage services focus on itself being your main storage and your hard drive a backup. It should be the other way round

Answer (score 1):

This is a little old now, but for anyone visiting, rclone is now very mature and supported on both Windows (e.g. choco) and Linux. I used my windows machine to create the auth token and then used that to configure my linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in a classcial windows BAT shell script: You first map OneDrive as  a standard Windows net work drive, and then perform operations on it:

```
net use OneDriveMountPoint "https://d.docs.live.net/OneDriveCID" /USER:OneDriveUser /P:No
```

Whereas `OneDriveMoutPoint` is a free windows drive letter you like use, e.g. `Y:`; `OneDriveCID` is your OneDrive ID which you see when you log into OneDrive via a Browser (the URL comes back as something like `https://onedrive.live.com/?id=..whatever...&cid=OneDriveCID`) and `OneDriveUser` is your Windows OneDrive user name (usually something like `john.smith@outlook.com`); so this could look like:

```
net use Y: "https://d.docs.live.net/XGS%WHATEVER53SFF" /USER:john.smith@outlook.com /P:No
```

When executing you are prompted to enter your Windows OneDrive password (you can as well hardcode it in the net use call to avoid the prompt, but that is not recommended for obvious security concerns).

After that you have OneDrive mounted as network drive which now shows up in Windows Explorer and can by easily accessed with shell commands, like synchronization copy backup operations:

```
robocopy C:/mydatalocal Y:/mydataonedrive /MIR
```

(assuming your mount point is `Y:` and the folders exist). Note that the remote target OneDrive folder `mydataonedrive` must be set up to non-synchronize in your local windows settings, else all in the remote folder will automatically synchronize back into your local OneDrive folder structure...

You may want to destroy the link after the operation for security reasons with:

```
net use Y: /delete
```

Answer (score -1):

Found a better one that deals with alternate install locations...
There is an environment variable for it:
`Explorer.exe %OneDrive%` for File Explorer
`%OneDrive%` for Batch files
and
`$Env:OneDrive` for Powershell

There is also a different one on my system for `%OneDriveConsumer%` that is set to the same location on my system, so not sure what that is for...

Comment: %OneDriveConsumer% is used for the common onedrive included with the Microsoft account, if you have a work or school account %OneDriveCommercial% appears in environment variables, and the default path %OneDrive% is set to the commercial as well.

Comment: This does not answer anything